# Input - Limit number range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a text `input` which I want to limit to only numbers. No other characters. I also want to limit from 0 - 255.

If a an 'illegal' char, or amount is entered, I want it to wait a second then delete that character or number. I was so far able to get the illegal characters.

Here's what I want to do:

- Make it wait a second, then delete it.
- Limit number from 0 - 255.

If more than 255 gets entered, I just want the last digit to wait, then delete itself. Just like the 'illegal' chars.

I already got the illegal character implemented. Here's the code:

#### JSFiddle

```js
$('input[name="number"]').keyup(function(e) {
  if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) {
    // Filter non-digits from input value.
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="number" />
```

Comment: Newer browsers support using `<input type="number" min="0" max="255">`

Comment: @Horay See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @guest271314 Here's the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142122/limit-text-input-to-numbers-only-with-range

Comment: @Horay See updated post. Removed `.queue()` portion as not necessary

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `if` condition to check if `this.value` is greater than `255` , if true , set `this.value` to first two characters of input using `String.prototype.slice()`

> How about making it wait a second?

Try using `setTimeout()`

```js
function disableInput(el) {
  // create array of checks on `el.value`
  var checks = [/\D/g.test(el.value), el.value > 255];
  // if `el.value` contains non-digit character,
  // or is greater than 255 ;
  // `Array.prototype.some()` checks for `true` value
  // if either `checks[0]`, or `checks[1]` is `true` do stuff
  // else set `el.value` to user input
  if (checks.some(Boolean)) {
    // disable input
    $(el).prop("disabled", true)
    // delay 1 second
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (checks[0]) {
        // Filter non-digits from input value.
        el.value = el.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
      }
      // if `this.value` greater than 255 , set `this.value` to 
      // first two characters of input
      if (checks[1]) {
        el.value = el.value.slice(0, 2);
      };
      $(el).prop("disabled", false).val(el.value).focus()
    }, 1000)
  }      

}


$('input[name="number"]').keyup(function(e) {
  disableInput(this)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="number" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But if you enter a value more than 255, I don't want it to go back to 255, I just wan the last number to get removed.

Comment: Nice answer, although it would "look" nicer if `keydown` were used ;)

Comment: _"But if you enter a value more than 255, I don't want it to go back to 255, I just wan the last number to get removed"_ If `256` is input, result should be `25` ?

Comment: @Horay See updated post. Substituted using `.slice()` for setting `this.value` to `255`

Comment: @guest271314 That works! How about making it wait a second?

Comment: @Horay _"That works! How about making it wait a second?"_ What should occur if user inputs value during one second "wait" period ?

Comment: @Horay _"Yes"_ ? Should `input` be disabled during one second period ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes. It should be disabled

Comment: @Horay See Try using `.queue()` , `setTimeout` ; see updated post

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks! Can you please explain the `disableInput` function?

Comment: @guest271314 Also, it now allows letters. How can make it not allow letters like before?

Comment: @Horay `input`:`el`  and `input.value`:`val` are passed as parameters , `disabled` set at `input` ; `.queue()` queues a function to call, `setTimeout` calls `.dequeue()` after 1 second, `disabled` set to `false`

Comment: @Horay _"Also, it now allows letters. How can make it not allow letters like before?"_ See updated post

Comment: There is 1 more issue. I hope.... :)  It looses focus  when an illegal char was entered

Comment: @Horay `disabled` input cannot have `focus`  ; added `.focus()` after 1 second delay within `disableInput` ; see updated post

Comment: Thanks! Also, say you enter '35'. If you move the cursor back and you enter another number, so now we would have '315'. It then deletes 5, not 1. How can we make it delete the number we entered?

Comment: @Horay _"Also, say you enter '35'. If you move the cursor back and you enter another number, so now we would have '315'. It then deletes 5, not 1. How can we make it delete the number we entered?"_ `35` is valid entry , `5` should not be deleted . If change cursor position and enter `315` that would be new value of `input` , an invalid entry. Why would `1` be deleted ?

Comment: Right, so 1 should get deleted because that was the last entered char. But in the above code, the 5 gets deleted. I want the last **entered** number to get deleted. Do you understand?

Comment: @Horay _"Right, so 1 should get deleted because that was the last entered char. But in the above code, the 5 gets deleted. I want the last entered number to get deleted. Do you understand?"_ Yes; if user changes input from `31` , a valid entry,  to `315` , an invalid entry , `5` would be the last number entered , not `1`

Comment: If you have '35' Then you move the cursor in between 3 and 5, then enter 1. So we now have '315'. The order of number inserted would be: 3, 5 then 1. '1' is the last number entered.

Comment: @guest271314 So I want '1' to get removed. Get it?

Comment: @Horay _"If you have '35' Then you move the cursor in between 3 and 5, then enter 1. So we now have '315'. The order of number inserted would be: 3, 5 then 1. '1' is the last number entered. "_ This is entirely different requirement from what is described at original Question. Original Question does not require each individual input value to be stored in the order it was entered.

Comment: So should I ask it as a new question?

Comment: _"So should I ask it as a new question?"_ Yes, including all specific requirements in actual Question, rather than adding more requirements at comments after Question posted

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much for being patient and helping me!! +1 to your answer!