# Limit text input to numbers only

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I want to implement a text `input` with the following implementations:

- Only allow numbers
- Limit numbers from 0 - 255
- If an 'illegal' character was entered (non numbers, or over or under 255), the `input` should get disabled, wait a second, then delete the invalid char, and get back to focus.

I got all that implemented thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34127420/5244870). There's an issue though. If you enter 35 (that's 'legal'), then move the cursor between 3 and 5, then enter 1, which comes out to 315. That becomes 'illegal' because it's more than 255. So the 5 gets deleted. I don't want the 5 to get removed, I want the 1 to get deleted because that was the last one entered.

But if you enter 31, then 5, 5 should get removed. Basically, I want the last number **entered** to get deleted when an illegal amount gets inserted.

Also, I want the cursor to go to the position of the last removed character, whether it's a number or letter.

Here's the code:

#### JSFiddle

```js
function disableInput(el) {
  var checks = [/\D/g.test(el.value), el.value > 255];
  if (checks.some(Boolean)) {
    $(el).prop("disabled", true)
      .queue("disabled", function() {
        $(this).prop("disabled", false)
      });
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (checks[0]) {
        el.value = el.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
      }
      if (checks[1]) {
        el.value = el.value.slice(0, 2);
      };
      $(el).dequeue("disabled").val(el.value).focus()
    }, 1000)
  }

}


$('input[name="number"]').keyup(function(e) {
  disableInput(this)
  $(this).focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="number" />
```

Comment: Can you leverage input[type=number]? `<input type="number" name="number" max="255" min="0" onchange="this.reportValidity()">`

Comment: It seems most of the code you already have is from that answer you linked, you didn't try to solve this "remove last number entered" problem yourself in any way, and are just asking others to write code for you instead of trying to understand the problem.

Comment: @amphetamachine That doesn't work because number allows you to enter 'illegal' values

Comment: @DJDavid98 I did try `if (checks[1]) {
        el.value = el.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
      }; And that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selectionStart and selectionEnd to see where the cursor is in the input and then use those values to remove the correct character.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o4bz0wr7/3/

```
function disableInput(el) {
  var checks = [/\D/g.test(el.value), el.value > 255];
  if (checks.some(Boolean)) {
    $(el).prop("disabled", true)
      .queue("disabled", function() {
        $(this).prop("disabled", false)
      });
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (checks[0] || checks[1]) {
        el.value = el.value.slice(0, el.selectionStart - 1) + el.value.slice(el.selectionEnd);
      }
      $(el).dequeue("disabled").val(el.value).focus()
    }, 1000)
  }

}


$('input[name="number"]').keyup(function(e) {
  disableInput(this)
  $(this).focus();
});
```

EDIT: You can set the cursor position using `setSelectionRange`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o4bz0wr7/7/

```
function disableInput(el) {
  var checks = [/\D/g.test(el.value), el.value > 255];
  if (checks.some(Boolean)) {
    $(el).prop("disabled", true)
      .queue("disabled", function() {
        $(this).prop("disabled", false)
      });
    setTimeout(function() {
      var start = el.selectionStart - 1;
      if (checks[0] || checks[1]) {
        el.value = el.value.slice(0, start) + el.value.slice(el.selectionEnd);
      }
      $(el).dequeue("disabled").val(el.value).focus();
      el.setSelectionRange(start, start);
    }, 1000)
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I get the cursor to go to the position of the last removed character?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine with you, however if there is still any problem add it in comment.

Check it out in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o4bz0wr7/8/)

```
var which = null;

function disableInput(el, $which) {
  console.log(el.value);
  var checks = [/\D/g.test(el.value), el.value > 255];
  if (checks.some(Boolean)) {
    $(el).prop("disabled", true)
      .queue("disabled", function() {
        $(this).prop("disabled", false)
      });
    setTimeout(function() {
     console.log(String.fromCharCode($which));
       el.value = el.value.replace($which, '');
       // el.value = el.value.slice(0,el.value.length - 1);


      $(el).dequeue("disabled").val(el.value).focus()
    }, 1000)
  }

}


$('input[name="number"]').keypress(function(e) {
    which = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    $(this).focus();
}).keyup(function(){
    disableInput(this, which);

})
```